# javascript variable not working inside html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want my html attribute to get the values from a javascript statement(function). It marks a portion block red on an image that is targeted by the co-ordinates inside the area tag. My full code is given below at the bottom.

This works perfectly fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<area href="#" select="red" shape="rect" coords="69,76,84,102">');
</script>
```

But for some reason reason, this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var crd=[69,76,84,102];
  document.write('<area href="#" select="red" shape="rect" coords="'+crd[0]+","+crd[1]+","+crd[2]+","+crd[3]+'">');
</script>
```

This is my html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mapping Physical Library</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <img id="pic" src="unnamed.png" usemap="#mark">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#pic').mapster({
            singleSelect : true,
            mapKey: 'select',
            fill : true,
            fillColor : 'FF0000',
            fillOpacity : 1,
            areas : [{key : 'red', selected : true}]
        });
    });
    </script>

    <map name="mark">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<area href="#" select="red" shape="rect" coords="69,76,84,102">');
        </script>       
    </map>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: doesn't work in what way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not work"? If you expect it to make dinner for you, then it's no surprise that "it does not work".

Comment: My bad. I should have been more clear.

Comment: You code works perfectly. I'd assume another error is being thrown in your page that is stopping that line from running.

Comment: Change <script src="scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script> to <script src="http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js?v1.2.10"></script>

Comment: @SlickRick I got it up and running now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    document.write('<area href="#" select="red" shape="rect" coords="'+crd[0]+"','"+crd[1]+"','"+crd[2]+"','"+crd[3]+'">');
```

you missed sing quot in comma(,)

or try this

```
document.write('<area href="#" select="red" shape="rect" coords="'+ crd.join(",")+'">');
```

Comment: The second one is fine, the first is incorrect. There is nothing wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: oh thx @FelixKling it was my mistake.
just ignore first one Plz